# Is there a way to manually invoke spring binding?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to manually invoke spring binding to create an object based on form post data?

Normally I would use something like this:

```
 @RequestMapping({"/url"})
 public String execute(MyBindingoObject object, BindingResult errors) {
    ///...
 }
```

But I am working in a project that uses a generic controller and passes in commands that do the actual work. Is there anyway to do something like this:

```
MyBindingObject object = SomeSpringUtil.bindObject(MyBindingObject.class, request);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/bind/support/WebRequestDataBinder.html